# How can I use Styles in Microsoft Word to only change specific formatting and keep other existing formatting unchanged?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, styles, layout, word-processing

I am trying to update multiple paragraphs of text with some complicated formatting (creating a blue line left of the paragraph). However I want the existing lay-out and formatting to remain the same.

Can I use Styles in Microsoft Word to only change this specific formatting (blue line) and keep other existing formatting (such as line spacing and font) unchanged?

Comment: There is no such an option in Word. In case you want to apply your *blue lined* style always on top of the same style, then you can just create a new style for that, based on the original style of the paragraph, so if you update your basic style, then also *blue lined* will also be updated. Also applying a paragraph level style won't change format changes you've applied at character level.

Answer (score 1):

However simple the question sounds, what you are asking seems to be impossible in Microsoft Word, at least using styles. This is because styles cannot be defined with properties set to 'keep unchanged' or something similar.

Instead, when applying a style, there is an internal algorithm that determines which formatting to keep and which formatting to override with the style's formatting. This algorithm is based on how much of the text has custom formatting. If it's just some words in bold, a single italicised sentence, or an occasional font change, Word doesn't touch that. Otherwise, the specific formatting change is overridden with the style's. Also, the way this works seems to be dependent on the *style type* (i.e. paragraph, character, linked, table or list).

I agree it's strange that they do not offer a built-in mechanism that allows only changes in certain formatting properties, whatever the style. For such things as a 'blue line' that doesn't change anything else in the text (which may consist of several completely different styles) I can see that such functionality would certainly be welcome.

However, if it would exist, this functionality would not be available using the 'styles' mechanism, as every piece of text can only have a single style. Changing the style to "blue lined" for example while in reality it would be a mix of styles (which is basically what we're after) opposes the idea of text having a single style.

Probably the best you can do if you have some complex formatting you want applied is using macros (VBA). Otherwise, you are stuck with manually applying your formatting to every paragraph.